# AS3 Simple movieclip rollOver question

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, button, rollover

Simple question..
I have 1 MC with buttonMode=true. There are 2 text fields nested inside 1 button graphic inside the MC. My question is that when I roll over my mouse to my button, the roll over effect is gone if I roll over my text fields....the mouse is still inside the button graphic but the roll over effect is gone....see below..

```
-------------------
|   textfield a   |
|   textfield b   | <-button
|                 |
-------------------
```

I hope I explain myself well...when I roll over to textfield a or b..the roll over effect for my button is gone...any ideas?? Thanks...

**Update:**

My structure is

MC contain 2 textfield and 1 button...
I set mybtn.mouseEnabled=false inside my MC timeline...
and it killed my mybtn rollover effect completely....

Comment: set mouseChildren = false for the button ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set

```
mouseChildren = false
```

on the container (ie. The button)
Or you can set the mouseEnabled property to false on each of the TextFiends.

Comment: Its not working......if I set mouseChildren=false...my button roll over effect will be completely gone......not sure why..+1 though

Answer (score 0):

u can place one more mc inside your parent mc. its like MC contain 2 textfield and 1 button also on the front of these textfields and button place one more mc and set the property alpha = 0; also in AS3 set the buttonMode = true; for this new mc. And last addEventListener for this mc MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT or whatever u want to use. Inside that functions do whatever u want

I hope this can work for you :))

i got and image for u but cant place it here sorry..